# update values in all tables using single query in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to update multiple columns using a single query in MySql with some condition that is valid across all colums.

I have around 25 databases with the same table structure in them. I need to update a field named `Status` across all databases for a particular url using a single query using **phpMyAdmin**.

Right now I am using this query. (I need to set `status=2` in `table1` in all of these databases  where the `url` is `'www.google.com'`)

```
UPDATE  `database1`.`table1` as p1,
    `database2`.`table1` as p2 ,
    `database3`.`table1` as p3
SET  p1.`STATUS` = 2,
    p2.`STATUS`= 2,
    p3.`STATUS`= 2 
WHERE p1.url='www.google.com' and
    p1.url=p2.url=p3.url
```

But it is updating data in all rows not only `url='www.google.com'`. It is updating `status=2` in `'www.yahoo.com'` also.

Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what you want:

```
UPDATE
    database1.table1 AS p1
    LEFT JOIN database2.table1 AS p2 USING (url)
    LEFT JOIN database3.table1 AS p3 USING (url)
SET
   p1.`STATUS` = 2,
   p2.`STATUS` = 2,
   p3.`STATUS` = 2
WHERE
    url = 'www.google.com';
```

and your didn't work becouse of `p1.url=p2.url=p3.url`
thats evaluated as `p1.url=(p2.url=p3.url)`
where `(p2.url=p3.url)` => FALSE for all that didn't match,
and then we end up with `p1.url=FALSE`

comparing `p1.url=FALSE` => comparing a string with an boolean,
converting the string to an integer gives 0 for non numeric string,
and converting boolean FALSE to integer gives also 0, so `p1.url=FALSE`

so `p1.url=p2.url=p3.url` is the same as `NOT p2.url=p3.url`

so your code update all rows where there exists a p2.url thats not equal to all p3.urls

Comment: for deleting the rows, should I do following  DELETE
 from    database1.table1 AS p1
    LEFT JOIN database2.table1 AS p2 USING (url)
    LEFT JOIN database3.table1 AS p3 USING (url)
WHERE
    url = 'www.google.com';