# MYSQL replace domain for domain

Tags: mysql

I am trying to replace a domain - domain.co.nz with another domain - domain.com.au I am picking this can be done via `update` but can I use * instead of setting each table - I am basically wanting to do a find and replace.

Comment: Possibly already answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11863792/update-values-in-all-tables-using-single-query-in-mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to replace each occurence of `domain.co.nz` in your database, you'll need to know each table, and each column affected.

The simplest and quickest way to do it is to make a dump of your database, find & replace your domain in a text editor, and re-import the result.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't `update *` (would it have been so hard to try it out yourself?). In addition to specifying a table you also need to specify a column - and really the point of using a database is so you can store data in a location where you know where to retrieve it from / modify it - i.e. the question hints at some very bad database design.

You can get a list of the tables an their columns from the [information schema](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html) database. It's quite possible to iterate through all the tables using a procedural cursor, and iterating through all columns in each table to create an update statement then prepare/exec the statement. But the code to implement this goes way beyond an answer here.

The answer by zessx is the most practical solution if you can afford the downtime.